# Trying to PHP session a google utm query string and parse it with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, utm

I'm trying to PHP session a Google UTM query string, then parse it in JSON. I'm trying to make sure that I don't get any errors. I want to session the url query string, which has the google utm parameters(adwords campaign) then parse the values and insert them into a hidden form fields. Does this look correct? My code is below. Let me know. Thank you!

```
<?php

if (!session_id()) 
{
    session_start();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['googy'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['googy'] =  $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]; 
}

if (isset ($_SESSION['googy']) )
    $goo .= $_SESSION['googy'];

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var query = '<?php echo $goo; ?>';
query = query.replace(/%20/g," ");
query = query.replace(/%21/g,"!");
query = query.replace(/%22/g,'"');
query = query.replace(/%23/g,"#");
query = query.replace(/%24/g,"$");
query = query.replace(/%25/g,"%");
query = query.replace(/%26/g,"&");
query = query.replace(/%27/g,"'");
query = query.replace(/%28/g,"(");
query = query.replace(/%29/g,")");
query = query.replace(/%2A/g,"*");
query = query.replace(/%2B/g,"+");
query = query.replace(/%2C/g,",");
query = query.replace(/%2D/g,"-");
query = query.replace(/%2E/g,".");
query = query.replace(/%2F/g,"/");

var parameters = {};

if (query) {
    var search_arr = query.split("&");
    for (var item in search_arr) {
        if (search_arr[item]) {
            var item_arr = search_arr[item].split("=");
            if (item_arr[1]) {
            parameters[item_arr[0]] = item_arr[1];
            }
        }
    }
}

if (JSON.stringify(parameters) != '{}') {
    for (var prop in parameters) {
        jQuery("#" + prop).val(parameters[prop]);
    }

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please **read the manual** before writing monstrosities like this. There's a function called [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for PHP and [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) for JavaScript that handles strings like that. It's important to develop a sense of what sort of things should be a solved problem and go looking for the right tool rather than hammering together your own instead.

Comment: "Does this look correct?" Well, does it work? If it works, it must be at least mostly correct. If it doesn't work, rework your question to say how it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you both. I believe it works now. Although, before I had query.length and item_arr[1].length and I was getting "file name too long error" in Apache and "Uncaught property 'length'" in the console log. So, I wasn't sure if I needed length anymore.